# how to use webmethod with telerik batch edit grid

Tags: jquery, .net, telerik, telerik-grid, webmethod

Work on Asp.net vs2012 C# telerik:RadGrid batch edit,I put save button outside from the grid.Under the save button want to call webmethod  to save all changes on my db.
Sample will be preferable,how to use webmethod with batch edit grid.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use RadClientDataSource to bind to your service: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/client-side/client-data-source-binding/defaultcs.aspx